# Best practice for returning a async promise for do while loops

Tags: javascript

What is the best practice to return a promise for this function:

```
function calculateTextSize(guide){

      do {
          default_size -= 0.1;
          text_Height = getTextHeight(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`) + 10;     
      }
      while (text_Height > height);    

      do {
          default_size -= 0.1;
          text_Length = getTextWidth(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`).toFixed(2);               
      }
      while (text_Length > width);

};
```

I want to wait for `calculateTextSize` in an async function like:

```
async function foo(){
 await calculateTextSize();
 //After calculateTextSize has finished its work do stuff..
}
```

I have tried this but  I'm not sure if it's the best or at least good practice: (If Javascript compiler first wait for the do while loop to be finished and then goes to the next line it could be the good practice, but I don't know how JS compiler behaves with do while loops)

```
  function calculateTextSize(guide){

          do {
              default_size -= 0.1;
              text_Height = getTextHeight(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`) + 10;     
          }
          while (text_Height > height);    

          do {
              default_size -= 0.1;
              text_Length = getTextWidth(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`).toFixed(2);               
          }
          while (text_Length > width);

         return new Promise((resolve) => { 
         resolve();
         });

    };
```

**UPDATE:** Here is the `getTextWidth` function:

```
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
      var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.font = font;
      var metrics = context.measureText(text);
      return metrics.width;
      };

      //Start Of Text Height Function
      function getTextHeight(text, font) {
      let canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
      let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      let sourceWidth = canvas.width;
      let sourceHeight = canvas.height;

      context.font = font;

      // place the text somewhere
      context.textAlign = "left";
      context.textBaseline = "top";
      context.fillText(text, 25, 5);

      // returns an array containing the sum of all pixels in a canvas
      // * 4 (red, green, blue, alpha)
      // [pixel1Red, pixel1Green, pixel1Blue, pixel1Alpha, pixel2Red ...]
      let data = context.getImageData(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight).data;

      let firstY = -1;
      let lastY = -1;

      // loop through each row
      for(let y = 0; y < sourceHeight; y++) {
        // loop through each column
        for(let x = 0; x < sourceWidth; x++) {
            //var red = data[((sourceWidth * y) + x) * 4];
            //var green = data[((sourceWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 1];
            //var blue = data[((sourceWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 2];
            let alpha = data[((sourceWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 3];

            if(alpha > 0) {
                firstY = y;
                // exit the loop
                break;
            }
        }
        if(firstY >= 0) {
            // exit the loop
            break;
        }

      }

      // loop through each row, this time beginning from the last row
      for(let y = sourceHeight; y > 0; y--) {
        // loop through each column
        for(let x = 0; x < sourceWidth; x++) {
            var alpha = data[((sourceWidth * y) + x) * 4 + 3];
            if(alpha > 0) {
                lastY = y;
                // exit the loop
                break;
            }
        }
        if(lastY >= 0) {
            // exit the loop
            break;
        }

      }

      return lastY - firstY;

      };
```

Comment: `calculateTextSize` function doesn't return a Promise. It's just a function performing something in a while loop synchronously(assuming `getTextHeight` is synchronous). Why are you using await on it?

Comment: Is there a possibility that the function will fail?

Comment: But are you doing any asynchronous tasks inside `calculateTextSize`? If not then there's no reason to return a promise.

Comment: `calculateTextSize` sometimes takes more time than expected and codes after it in `foo` will fail.. Currently I' using setTimeout to delay the code after `calculateTextSize`

Comment: If `getTextWidth` does what I think it does (renders text, then measures it), it is a) synchronous, so promises will not help you at all, and 2) the reason why your function is so slow. Every time you read DOM after changing it, the browser triggers a layout (and repaint), so the measurement will be accurate. To speed it up, render _all_ texts you want to measure, then take _all_ measurements. It will still be synchronous, promises will still be useless, but it will take much less time. EDIT: never mind, I see what you're doing, and you need the loop. Then at least do a binary search...

Comment: To summarise, there is no way to make changes to DOM asynchronous, since layouts are executing on the main thread. WebWorkers can make calculation in parallel, but they can't touch the DOM; and obviously waiting for external stuff to finish is async. In your case, there is nothing async, or promises, can do for you.

Comment: Thanks for the great comments .. they really helped ...

Comment: @Amadan Please have a look at my update...

Comment: I think you were right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrappe your function code in a promise object and resolve or reject based on the data.

```
function calculateTextSize(guide) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        do {
            default_size -= 0.1;
            text_Height = getTextHeight(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`) + 10;
        }
        while (text_Height > height);
        do {
            default_size -= 0.1;
            text_Length = getTextWidth(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`).toFixed(2);
        }
        while (text_Length > width);

        resolve(`< return data >`);
    });
};
```

Call the function like this

```
calculateTextSize()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Or use async await to call the function.

```
(async function () {
        try {
            let data = await calculateTextSize();
            console.log(data);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function doesn't do any asynchronous tasks then it's better to avoid promises. 
Anyway if you want to return a promise after your loops then you should change that to something like this:

```
  function calculateTextSize(guide){
   return new Promise((resolve) => { 
          do {
              default_size -= 0.1;
              text_Height = getTextHeight(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`) + 10;     
          }
          while (text_Height > height);    

          do {
              default_size -= 0.1;
              text_Length = getTextWidth(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`).toFixed(2);               
          }
          while (text_Length > width);
          resolve();
          });
    };
```

Since we're resolving after the loops this will ensure that your calculations are done prior to resolving.

Answer (score 0):

```
If I understand well then you need perform the followings;-
/* await look for a promise , so I will create calculateTextSize() function which return promise.*/

async function foo(){
 await calculateTextSize();
 //After calculateTextSize has finished its work do stuff..
}

return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => { 
       try{
         do {
              default_size -= 0.1;
              text_Height = await getTextHeight(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`);
              text_Height = text_Height + 10     
          }
          while (text_Height > height);    

          do {
              default_size -= 0.1;
              text_Length = await getTextWidth(guide, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`); 
              text_Length = text_Length.toFixed(2)              
          }
          while (text_Length > width);
          resolve();
          });
       }catch(error){
         reject(error)
       }


    };
// getTextHeight is also look like a function which need to return promise so 

getTextHeight(guide,someStr){
    return Promise (async (resolve,reject) => {
        try{
         //do your stuff     
         resolve()
        }catch(error){
          reject(error)
        }
    })
}
```